# How to successfully call the following dll method in C# using PInvoke

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I've tried searching online for an answer to my question to no avail.

I have a C/C++ DLL with the following struct and method:

```
typedef struct AVPacket {
    int64_t pts;
    int64_t dts;
    uint8_t *data;
    int size;
    int stream_index;
    int flags;
    int duration;
    void (*destruct) (struct AVPacket *);
    void *priv;
    int64_t pos;
} AVPacket;

typedef AVPacket * HAVPacket;

HAVPacket __stdcall ffCreateAVPacket(bool fillWithZero);
```

Now my C# code looks as follows:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct AVPacket
{
    public Int64 pts;
    public Int64 dts;
    public byte[] data;
    public int size;
    public int stream_index;
    public int flags;
    public int duration;
    public IntPtr destruct;
    public IntPtr priv; 
    public Int64 pos;
}

[DllImport(dll, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
static extern void ffCreateAVPacket(bool fillWithZero, out AVPacket packet);
```

Which I call using:

```
AVPacket packet;

ffCreateAVPacket(true, out packet);
```

I'm getting a PInvokeStackImbalance exception stating: A call to PInvoke has unbalanced the stack.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: your C++ method looks like "HAVPacket __stdcall ffCreateAVPacket(bool fillWithZero);". But you have changed C# version. I think it should be: static extern IntPtr ffCreateAVPacket(bool fillWithZero). After getting a pointer, you should cast it to AVPacket. Use this code: AVPacket avPacket  = (AVPacket)Marshal.PtrToStructure(YOUR_POINTER, typeof(AVPacket));

Comment: Also if you're using FFMPEG, look [AvPacket structure](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/avcodec_8h_source.html) and its [unsafe port for C#](https://github.com/Ruslan-B/FFmpeg.AutoGen/blob/master/FFmpeg.AutoGen/FFmpeg.avcodec.g.cs#L69), because your AVPacket is differ

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have fixed my problem. Also, I will have a look at the port for C#. I'm currently working with the ffdec project.